# The relation between PDE order and discretization order

Tags: pde, finite-volume, discretization, navier-stokes, openfoam

In [Jasak's Ph.D. thesis (2000)](http://powerlab.fsb.hr/ped/kturbo/OpenFOAM/docs/HrvojeJasakPhD.pdf), a notion is given about discretization of a transport equation:
**For good accuracy, it is necessary for the order of the discretization to
be equal to or higher than the order of the equation that is being discretized.**
*Question:*
Why?

Comment: How do you define **good accuracy**? How much accuracy is **good**? It's a pretty bad idea to use good or bad for something that could be measured quantitatively.

Comment: Putting away the definition of **good accuracy**, does PDE order dictate any requirement or optimum choice for discretization order?

Comment: No. I see no connection between the two.

Comment: If you were doing FEM, say for the Poisson problem, you wouldn't want to use DG0 space discretization because the corresponding bilinear form $-\left<\{Q\nabla u\cdot\hat{n}\},[v]\right> + \sigma \left<[u],\{Q\nabla v\cdot\hat{n}\}\right> + \kappa \left<\{h^{-1}Q\}[u],[v]\right>$ would be all zeros except for the contribution from the penalty term $\kappa \left<\{h^{-1}Q\}[u],[v]\right>$. Still there is nothing wrong with it as far as I know, just doesn't feel good.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, How if I do FVM? Can a similar argument be applied there?

Comment: @Alish, I only know FVM at textbook level and in no way an expert in the topic. I can contribute two things though. Firstly, one solves for the cell averages with FVMs, contrary to FEMs. So the order of discretization in the sense of FEMs is slightly different than FVMs and I don't think my argument generalizes. Secondly, for the transport equation $u_t + \vec{a}\cdot\nabla u = 0$, DG0 in space is equivalent to some FVM and there is no problem using it. Thus, even though the PDE is first order and the discretization is zeroth order, it is all good.